# Prestashop: add product with my custom price to cart

Tags: php, module, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

in prestashop (1.6.1.5) on product detail page I have my custom price for the current product.
Now when I click on "add to cart" the standard product is added to the cart with standard price. I will add the product with my custom price to cart .

Could anyone give me some needable ideas in the right direction please...

Thank you very much